# MATLAB: How do I copy files with a specific extension to a folder one directory above it?

Tags: matlab, copy, file-copying

I am trying to copy specific files from one folder into another folder one directory above it. I want to do this for all of the folders I have at once. Here's my file structure:

201415ContinuousForDropTeqc/StationA/201411/
This path has 25 folders labeled 5 through 30 (representing days).
In each of these 25 folders there are 3 folders named 'dat', 'RAW', 'rinex'. 
I want all files ending in .14o from the RAW folder (there are many other file types in this folder as well) to be copied to the rinex folder.

I'm also hoping I can find a way to repeat this for every day in the 201411 folder. This last part isn't critical since I *think* can type the path manually and just run the script that copy and pastes the files I want.

I hope this was clear. I'm new-ish to MatLab.

Thank you in advance for your help!
Tiffany

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that using the `dir` command. [Check this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html?refresh=true).
You can use it twice. first to get all the 25 folders and then to get all the files within the folder.

```
Days = dir('201415ContinuousForDropTeqc/StationA/201411/');
for k=3:numel(Days) %notice the 3
  files = dir([Days(k).name '/RAW/*.14o']);
  for n=1:numel(files)
    copyfile([Days(k).name '/RAW/' files(n).name],[Days(k).name '/rinex/' files(n).name]);
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Line 3 is giving me an error I'm not sure about: Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object. It's almost like it doesn't know to go into that folder.

Comment: My mistake. You should use () rather than {}. I Will edited the answer.